# Can you create a DIXF processing group programmatically via web services and .NET?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

The Dynamics AX Import Export Framework (DIXF) has a graphical interface for creating data source formats, processing groups, etc.  But if one wanted to "drop in" an import/export job from an external application via web services, is there a way to do this programmatically?  Or is there some PowerShell utility one could use to work with DIXF without the GUI?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any out-of-the-box way to do this without using the GUI.  You can pretty easily dev something to do it yourself.  Here is some copy-pasta of some code I wrote to generate the things I needed.  You can do this via .Net too w/same type of code.

To create a processing group:

```
#define.DMFDefGroup('MyGroup')

DMFDefinitionGroup      dmfDefinitionGroup;

dmfDefinitionGroup = dmfDefinitionGroup::find(#DMFDefGroup);

if (!dmfDefinitionGroup)
{
    dmfDefinitionGroup.CompareType = DMFCompare::CopyEntity;
    dmfDefinitionGroup.DefinationGroupName = #DMFDefGroup;
    dmfDefinitionGroup.Description = 'Auto generated company data copy tool';
    dmfDefinitionGroup.insert();
}
```

Then I had some code like this to create the entities:

```
DMFDefinitionGroupEntity        dmfDefinitionGroupEntity;
DMFDataSource                   dmfDataSource = DMFDataSource::find('AX');
MyDMFAutoGenData               myDMFAutoGenData;
int64                             i;
DMFDefinationGroupName          groupName = dmfDefinitionGroup.DefinationGroupName;

while select myDMFAutoGenData
{
    i++;
    dmfDefinitionGroupEntity = DMFDefinitionGroupEntity::find(groupName, myDMFAutoGenData.TableName);

    if (!dmfDefinitionGroupEntity)
    {
        select count(RecId) from dmfDefinitionGroupEntity
            where dmfDefinitionGroupEntity.DefinitionGroup == groupName;

        dmfDefinitionGroupEntity.DefinitionGroup    = groupName;
        dmfDefinitionGroupEntity.Sequence           = int642int(dmfDefinitionGroupEntity.RecId) + 1;
        dmfDefinitionGroupEntity.Source             = dmfDataSource.SourceName;
        dmfDefinitionGroupEntity.Entity             = myDMFAutoGenData.TableName;
        dmfDefinitionGroupEntity.insert();
    }
}
```